# How to properly deal with concurrency in rails with puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, concurrency, constraints, puma

I have a Rails application on production that runs on a multithread web server, Puma. With the number of users increasing, I am starting to see some of my models with a unique active record validation on the username getting inserted twice in the db with two simultaneous calls at my APIs.

How is this possible? Where do I need to start to debug this?

Comment: You probably don't have unique DB index on that specific column, so the validation runs at the time when other transaction inserting this specific value isn't submitted yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model layer validations/constraints are fine but they do not guarantee data integrity as you already experienced. For real data integrity guaranteed, your ***only*** solution is database layer constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @Andrey's answer..I'll suggest you to read about [ActiveRecord::Locking](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). It'll prevent multiple threads to access same resource. This technique is particularly essential in case you are dealing with financial data.